# Private method declarations in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Do I have to DECLARE all private methods in .m class file inside

```
@interface ClassName()
  //Privare Methods
@end
```

before

```
@implementation ClassName
  // Implementation of Private & Instance methods
@end
```

for every method I am implementing & using OTHER THEN the instance methods (methods declared in .h file)?

X-Code 4 DOES NOT give me WARNING for ALL private methods but ONLY for few of them. For example, it warns me for methods I am calling inside gesture handler functions but not inside other routines/methods. I am confused as to declare all non-instance methods or just declare the ones I get warned for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode won't warn about methods that appear before the point of invocation:

```
@implementation 

- (void) foo:(float)x;
{
    NSLog(@"%f", x); // prints 15.000000
}

- (void) bar;
{
    [self foo:15.0]; // no warning
    [self baz:15.0]; // warning
}

- (void) baz:(float)x;
{
    NSLog(@"%f", x); // prints 0.000000 instead of 15.0
}

@end
```

It is strongly recommended to declare methods which you are warned about, the code above gives one example why.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Now is it a good practice to declare private methods or not? I guess its good to declare them.

Comment: @Alex It is. Some people even use “Treat warnings as errors” compiler option, so the code won't compile unless the declarations are present.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to declare every method you implement.  The declaration is needed when the method you call is defined after the method which is calling it in .m file:

```
- (void) methodA {
     [self methodB]; //here you will get a warning if you don't define methodB it in a private class extention
}

- (void) methodB {
}
```